# Variable Width Footer with Centered Links

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, centering

My footer currently has a series of links of varying size that, as the page's width decreases, automatically wrap around to the next line.

```
<ul class="footer-links">
  <li>text 1</li>
  <li>text 2</li>
  <li>text 3</li>
  <li>longer text 1</li>
  <li>text 4</li>
  <li>text 5</li>
  <li>longer text 2</li>
  <li>much longer text 1</li>
  <li>longer text 3</li>
  <li>text 6</li>
  <li>much longer text 2</li>
  <li>very much longer text 1</li>
  <li>text 7</li>
  <li>longer text 4</li>
</ul>
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/X6EWn/

What I want is to get each of the rows to always be centered, even as the links wrap around.

Any ideas on how this can be accomplished?

Comment: The  why don't you make them inline ? http://jsfiddle.net/X6EWn/1/

Comment: "each of the rows centered" like this? http://jsfiddle.net/X6EWn/2/

Comment: Thanks drip, but I wanted the sections to remain solid yours splits 'very much longer text 1' across lines as it wraps... Lucio, I wanted the wrap around still...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you what you want. See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/harveyramer/NF2tm/

```
ul.footer-links {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}

ul.footer-links > li {
    margin: 3px 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Perfect... I must have had a brain lapse, because this is too simple... thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

Harvey hit the nail on the head. However, it can be bettered by setting the `ul`s `font-size` to 0, then declaring the `fontsize` on the `li`, in order to remove that pesky white space in between each `li`. Code Below...

```
ul.footer-links {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
}

ul.footer-links > li {
    margin: 3px 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    font: 100 12px/20px 'Arial', sans-serif;
}
```

Original credit goes to Harvey for answering first.

Comment: eh, that looks very hacky and I use padding/margins in the real footer... thanks for the idea though

Comment: How is it "very hacky"? There's nothing invalid or out of the norm of doing this. It's a technique that's been used for years that just allows you to remove the unneeded space that's automatically generated between each `li`

Comment: I am saying that rather than using font-size to remove space between objects, I would rather use the box model (padding/margin)... Besides, adjusting the spacing is not part of the question

Comment: I understand that's not part of the question, but if something is thrown out such as "very hacky", I don't think it's reasonable to ask for an explanation.